# Selenium C# Object not into view while selecting from dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to select a value from a drop down, but when i try to select it i am getting the error that the object is not into view. All other fields on the same page can be filled fine, its just the drop down that is giving me issues.

Code:

```
driver.FindElementById("amount").SendKeys(amount);
            var element = driver.FindElementById("dial-code");

            element.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace + Keys.Backspace + cc);

            driver.FindElementById("displayed-phone").SendKeys(number);
            driver.FindElementById("message").SendKeys("Payment for " + code);
            driver.FindElementById("currency").Click();
```

Where currency is the id of the dropdown.

HTML:

```
<select id="currency" class="form-select form-medium" name="currency" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Select currency" aria-invalid="false">
                                        <option data-min="0.1" data-max="2000" data-precision="2" value="EUR">
                            EUR</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.11" data-max="2267.9" data-precision="2" value="USD">
                            USD</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.43" data-max="8586.52" data-precision="2" value="PLN">
                            PLN</option>
                                        <option data-min="4.26" data-max="85191.21" data-precision="2" value="ARS">
                            ARS</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.09" data-max="1769.03" data-precision="2" value="GBP">
                            GBP</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.15" data-max="3001.83" data-precision="2" value="CAD">
                            CAD</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.47" data-max="9321.04" data-precision="2" value="RON">
                            RON</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.16" data-max="3135.05" data-precision="2" value="AUD">
                            AUD</option>
                                        <option data-min="2.59" data-max="51860.98" data-precision="2" value="CZK">
                            CZK</option>
                                        <option data-min="129" data-max="2571679" data-precision="0" value="KRW">
                            KRW</option>
                                        <option data-min="77" data-max="1530190" data-precision="0" value="CLP">
                            CLP</option>
                                        <option data-min="13" data-max="256158" data-precision="0" value="JPY">
                            JPY</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.43" data-max="8684.11" data-precision="2" value="BRL">
                            BRL</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.6" data-max="11991.5" data-precision="2" value="TRY">
                            TRY</option>
                                        <option data-min="8.01" data-max="160286.6" data-precision="2" value="INR">
                            INR</option>
                                        <option data-min="7.51" data-max="150163" data-precision="2" value="RUB">
                            RUB</option>
                                        <option data-min="32.26" data-max="645136.78" data-precision="2" value="HUF">
                            HUF</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.17" data-max="3342.54" data-precision="2" value="NZD">
                            NZD</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.79" data-max="15758.7" data-precision="2" value="CNY">
                            CNY</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.11" data-max="2262.06" data-precision="2" value="CHF">
                            CHF</option>
                                        <option data-min="3.75" data-max="75023.1" data-precision="2" value="THB">
                            THB</option>
                                        <option data-min="2.31" data-max="46292.05" data-precision="2" value="MXN">
                            MXN</option>
                                        <option data-min="1.03" data-max="20619.2" data-precision="2" value="SEK">
                            SEK</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.75" data-max="14927.74" data-precision="2" value="DKK">
                            DKK</option>
                                        <option data-min="361.82" data-max="7236419.13" data-precision="2" value="COP">
                            COP</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.97" data-max="19492.9" data-precision="2" value="NOK">
                            NOK</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.43" data-max="8509.14" data-precision="2" value="SAR">
                            SAR</option>
                                        <option data-min="2638" data-max="52752181" data-precision="0" value="VND">
                            VND</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.16" data-max="3119.04" data-precision="2" value="SGD">
                            SGD</option>
                                        <option data-min="3.51" data-max="70182.28" data-precision="2" value="TWD">
                            TWD</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.42" data-max="8330.02" data-precision="2" value="AED">
                            AED</option>
                                        <option data-min="1.57" data-max="31426.7" data-precision="2" value="ZAR">
                            ZAR</option>
                                        <option data-min="5.94" data-max="118835.44" data-precision="2" value="PHP">
                            PHP</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.38" data-max="7658.68" data-precision="2" value="PEN">
                            PEN</option>
                                        <option data-min="2.03" data-max="40577.18" data-precision="2" value="EGP">
                            EGP</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.89" data-max="17747.98" data-precision="2" value="HKD">
                            HKD</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.03" data-max="689.81" data-precision="3" value="KWD">
                            KWD</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.08" data-max="1609.09" data-precision="3" value="JOD">
                            JOD</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.11" data-max="2267.9" data-precision="2" value="PAB">
                            PAB</option>
                                        <option data-min="0.48" data-max="9519.37" data-precision="2" value="MYR">
                            MYR</option>
                                </select><button class="select-button form-medium valid" type="button"><span>
                            USD</span><svg class="icon icon-arrow_down-dims"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-arrow_down"></use></svg></button><div class="options"><div class="option" data-value="EUR">
                            EUR</div><div class="option selected" data-value="USD">
                            USD</div><div class="option" data-value="PLN">
                            PLN</div><div class="option" data-value="ARS">
                            ARS</div><div class="option" data-value="GBP">
                            GBP</div><div class="option" data-value="CAD">
                            CAD</div><div class="option" data-value="RON">
                            RON</div><div class="option" data-value="AUD">
                            AUD</div><div class="option" data-value="CZK">
                            CZK</div><div class="option" data-value="KRW">
                            KRW</div><div class="option" data-value="CLP">
                            CLP</div><div class="option" data-value="JPY">
                            JPY</div><div class="option" data-value="BRL">
                            BRL</div><div class="option" data-value="TRY">
                            TRY</div><div class="option" data-value="INR">
                            INR</div><div class="option" data-value="RUB">
                            RUB</div><div class="option" data-value="HUF">
                            HUF</div><div class="option" data-value="NZD">
                            NZD</div><div class="option" data-value="CNY">
                            CNY</div><div class="option" data-value="CHF">
                            CHF</div><div class="option" data-value="THB">
                            THB</div><div class="option" data-value="MXN">
                            MXN</div><div class="option" data-value="SEK">
                            SEK</div><div class="option" data-value="DKK">
                            DKK</div><div class="option" data-value="COP">
                            COP</div><div class="option" data-value="NOK">
                            NOK</div><div class="option" data-value="SAR">
                            SAR</div><div class="option" data-value="VND">
                            VND</div><div class="option" data-value="SGD">
                            SGD</div><div class="option" data-value="TWD">
                            TWD</div><div class="option" data-value="AED">
                            AED</div><div class="option" data-value="ZAR">
                            ZAR</div><div class="option" data-value="PHP">
                            PHP</div><div class="option" data-value="PEN">
                            PEN</div><div class="option" data-value="EGP">
                            EGP</div><div class="option" data-value="HKD">
                            HKD</div><div class="option" data-value="KWD">
                            KWD</div><div class="option" data-value="JOD">
                            JOD</div><div class="option" data-value="PAB">
                            PAB</div><div class="option" data-value="MYR">
                            MYR</div></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Request money from</label>
            <div class="form-control-input">
                <div id="phone" class="input-group input-group-medium input-group-phone small-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon flag">
                        <img class="flag-icon" src="/img/flags/svg/NL.svg">
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="dialCode" id="dial-code" value="31" class="form-control input-group-code dirty valid" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4">
                    <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" id="displayed-phone" class="form-control input-group-number error" placeholder="Type phone number" autocomplete="off" maxlength="16" aria-describedby="displayed-phone-error">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="displayed-phone-error" class="error form-control-error">Phone number is required.</div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <div class="form-control-input">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control form-medium error" aria-describedby="message-error" aria-invalid="true"></textarea>
            </div>
        <div id="message-error" class="error form-control-error">Message is required.</div></div>

        <input type="hidden" class="csrf" name="L1T9b7fT5g14JGEc" value="74bdb290ff621f31c284b88e26e380a9">


        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send request</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I already tried using an action to scroll down, but the issue seems to be that the dropdown is very long. That is causing issues because i cant select from the dropdown anymore.

Also tried using Javascript to change the value of the dropdown, but that doesnt work either:

```
  driver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('currency').value = 'USD';");
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has a functionality to work with the Drop-downs. Like this:

```
var dropdown = driver.FindElementById("dial-code");     
var selectElement = new SelectElement(dropdown);
//select by value
selectElement.SelectByValue("Jr.High"); 
// select by text
selectElement.SelectByText("HighSchool");
```

or shorter:

```
(new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""))).SelectByValue("");
```

This works with usual drop-downs. You will need **Selenium.Support** nuget package for this.